# Compiling error with ld in gcc : "undefined reference to ..."

Tags: c, windows, gcc, 32bit-64bit, mingw-w64

I'm on Windows 11 in 64 bit machine and for didactic purpose I'm trying to compile in 32 bit a C code (.c) with linked Assebly code (.s), with the following command:

`gcc -m32 <file.c> <file.s> -o <name_file>`

but the compilation failed reporting the following error:

`C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQPXOVR.o:e2_main.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to f collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

The MinGW version that I use is: `x86_64-8.1.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0`

I think the problem is in the `ld` linker, because compiling the same files but in 64 bits through the following command: `gcc -m64 <file.c> <file.s> -o <name_file>` does not give me an error (but it is not what I need, I need to compile them in 32 bits).

Below I report the code files that I should compile

**<file.c>**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x);

int score, trials;

void test(int x, int c) {
    trials++;
    int r = f(x);
    printf("Test %d: %d [corretto: %d]\n", trials, r, c);
    score += r == c;
}

int main() {

    test(3, -2);
    test(4, 5);
    test(7, 50);
    test(17, 460);

    printf("Risultato: %d/%d\n", score, trials);

    return 0;
}
```

**<file.s>**

```
.globl f

f:
    movl 4(%esp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, %eax
    imull $2, %eax
    imull %ecx, %eax
    movl $7, %edx
    imull %ecx, %edx
    subl %edx, %eax
    incl %eax
    ret
```

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

I would hugely appreciate any suggestions or guidance on what to do or try next, as I am a little stuck and unsure from here.

I also try to compile an other C code with `-m32` flag without linking anything and it seems to have worked.

I try to install `i686-8.1.0-release-posix-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0` but it doesn't seem to change anything when I compile with `-m32` .

Comment: Build both files into object files. Then use tools such as `objdump` or similar to look at the name expected by the C file, and what symbol is exported from the assembly file. It's not uncommon for assembly symbols to need a leading underscore (as in `_f` instead of plain `f`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Could you tell me why is underscore necessary? Is there any way to omit it? I read that it was used to uniquely define functions. Does it depend on how the .c file is compiled?

Comment: It's part of the [**ABI**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).